# How to get Taskmanager's GPU memory usage from C# code

Tags: c#, taskmanager, vram

I would like to grab the GPU memory usage (dedicated and shared) from my C# code. Are there any chances to get these infos via WDDM or performance counter? How does the Taskmanager get these infos?

Since I also need the usage of AMD cards in particular, I can unfortunately not use NVAPI for this.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter class, query for the "GPU Adapter Memory" counters.  Verify by running perfmon.exe

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 types of GPU memory - Dedicated Memory & Shared Memory. Dedicated memory remains smaller in size but GPU gives preference to this memory to do its operations.
In C#, I have developed below code, which returns me the current usage of both these memories. You can cross verify the result in Task Manager.

```
var category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("GPU Adapter Memory");
var counterNames = category.GetInstanceNames();
var gpuCountersDedicated = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
var gpuCountersShared = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
var result = 0f;

foreach (string counterName in counterNames)
{
    foreach (var counter in category.GetCounters(counterName))
    {
        if (counter.CounterName == "Dedicated Usage")
        {
            gpuCountersDedicated.Add(counter);
        }
        else if (counter.CounterName == "Shared Usage")
        {
             gpuCountersShared.Add(counter);
        }
    }
}

gpuCountersDedicated.ForEach(x =>
{
    _ = x.NextValue();
});

await Task.Delay(1000);

gpuCountersDedicated.ForEach(x =>
{
    result += x.NextValue();
});

Console.WriteLine("Dedicated memory usage: " + result);

result = 0f;

gpuCountersShared.ForEach(x =>
{
    _ = x.NextValue();
});

await Task.Delay(1000);

gpuCountersShared.ForEach(x =>
{
    result += x.NextValue();
});

Console.WriteLine("Shared memory usage: " + result);
```

Output:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40psW.png)

Task Manager:
[Snip from task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlKRv.png)